# Can an abstract super class hold the reference to child class's object in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have created a child class **InheritanceTest** which extends parent class **Parent**. Parent class is an abstract class and InheritanceTest class overrides the abstract method abstractMethod(). When I write, **Parent P = new InheritanceTest();**, it is working fine. But when I write, **`List<Number> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();`**, it is giving me compilation error saying that *"Type mismatch: cannot convert from `ArrayList<Integer>` to `ArrayList<Number>`"*

**Note:** Number is an abstract class which is extended by Integer class in jdk.

Please find below my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


abstract class Parent {
    public void test() {
      System.out.println("parent version of test called");
    }

    public abstract void abstractMehod();
}

public class InheritanceTest extends Parent{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ArrayList<Number> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Parent parent = new InheritanceTest();

    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("child version of test called");
    }

    @Override
    public void abstractMehod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Please explain me the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: How is it possible? If possible then will it be meaningful? Super class don't know about anything its sub-class. Make sure to avoid creating a cyclic dependencies.

Comment: In super class just keep the reference of itself instead of sub-class reference that make more sense.

Comment: Before you decide to post your question make sure that it contains correct examples. You need to understand that `<foo>` is treated as HTML tag (strange one but tag) so it will not be printed. To print it you need to either post it as code or change `<` to `&lt;`.